# How do I call a function with elaborated type specifier template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, function-declaration

I came across elaborated type specifiers in a function parameter list. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations)

> - the keyword class, struct, or union, followed by template name with template arguments (optionally qualified, optionally using template disambiguator), previously defined as the name of a class template.

the following would be valid C++ code:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {};

struct Bar{

    int Baz( struct Foo<class T> foo) {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

And indeed it compiles on the three major compilers. But I can't find a way how to call the function `Bar::Baz`, which seems reasonable, because it'd have to deduce `T`. To do this, it'd need to be a function template, which it isn't.

It obviously works when I change it to an explicit specialisation `int  Baz(struct Foo<int> foo)`.

What's the usecase for this?

Full example [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/xTjcfrcxn).

Answer (score 4):

> How do I call a function with elaborated type specifier template?

In exactly the same way as you would call a function that didn't have an elaborated type specifier:

```
Bar b{};
Foo<T> f{};
b.Baz(f);
```

And here are declarations equivalent to yours without using elaborted type specifiers:

```
class T;

struct Bar{
    int Baz(Foo<T> foo) {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

> What's the usecase for this?

Elaborated type specifiers are used in C to refer to struct and union tags that don't have a type alias. Furthermore, they can be used to disambiguate a tag that conflicts with another name. They also implicitly behave as as struct / union declaration in a context where the declaration is being used. Some programmers dislike this and prefer a distinct declaration instead.

In C++, the first case isn't needed. The second case can be needed, although it's advisable to avoid such name conflicts when possible. Besides that, they are needed for cross-language compatibility.

Comment: Ahh, hehe, this looks so similar to a template declaration that I wasn't able to see the obvious. Sometines C++ is really confusing... Thank you!

Comment: @florestan Only sometimes? :)

Comment: Yeah, sure, only sometimes :)